# C# Access database update problems - beginner

Tags: c#, database, exception

I have no idea why the program isnt working, its practically the same code I used in the last project so why wont the database update? The code for the program is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;  

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    // This class will contain methods and fields needed to handle the data. 
    class Data
    {
        // Fields -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private static System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        private static System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
        private static System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

        public static DataSet ds1; // tblCars
        public static DataSet ds2; //tblStaff

        private static string sql;
        private static string dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
        private static string dbSource = "Data Source = E:\\cars.accdb";

        private static string userName;
        private static string userPin;

        private static string reg;

        private static bool valid;

        public static int numOfRowsCars;
        public static int numOfRowsStaff;

        public static int Index =0;

        public static string make;
        public static string model;
        public static string registration;
        public static string mileage;
        public static string yearMade;
        public static string price;
        public static string imageNav;

        // Methods -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public static void loadDB()
        {
            // load data into datasets  - this will be called on form2 the login screen            

             con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
             loadTblStaff();
             loadTblCars();             
        }

        public static void loadTblStaff()
        {
            // prepare, open and load the staff table into dataset ds2

            con.Open();

                sql = "SELECT * FROM tblStaff";
                ds2 = new DataSet();

                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
                numOfRowsStaff = da.Fill(ds2, "tblStaff");

            con.Close();

        }

        public static void loadTblCars()
        {
            // prepare, open and load the cars table into dataset ds1

            con.Open();

                sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCars";
                ds1 = new DataSet();

                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
                numOfRowsCars = da.Fill(ds1, "tblCars");

            con.Close();
        }       

        public static int Validate(string Name, string Pin)
        {
            // this method will be used to validate login credentials - it will return 0 for invalid, 1 for staff privalages and 2 for admin

            // check to see if log in details are valid
            for (int count = 0; count < numOfRowsStaff; count++)
            {
                userName = ds2.Tables["tblStaff"].Rows[count][0].ToString();
                userPin = ds2.Tables["tblStaff"].Rows[count][1].ToString();

               // MessageBox.Show("username: " + userName + '\n' + "Pin Number: " + userPin);

                if (Name == userName && Pin == userPin)
                {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }          

            if (valid && Pin == "9999")
            {
                // returning 2 will load the admin screen
               return 2;
            }
            else if (valid)
            {
                // returning 1 will load the staff screen
               return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // returning 0 will clear the input fields and return an error message
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public static int search(string Registration)
        {
            // this method will search for registration, if found it will return the index value , else it will return max value + 1          

            for (int count = 0; count < numOfRowsCars; count++)
            {
                reg = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[count][2].ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(reg);
                if (Registration == reg)
                {
                    // Then return the index of the registration number                     
                    return count;
                }               
            }
            return numOfRowsCars;                
        }

        public static void updateForm3()
        {
            // This method will create a new instance of Form3 with the update value of the index - this method will be called any time data needs changed
            Form3 updated = new Form3();
            updated.Show();

        }

        public static void updateForm4()
        {
            // This method will create a new instance of Form3 with the update value of the index - this method will be called any time data needs changed

            Form4 updated = new Form4();            
            updated.Show();
        }

        public static void loadRecords(int Index)
        {
            // This method will be used to load the appropriate values - It will take an index as its parameters

            // load the appropriate data
           make = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][0].ToString();
           model = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][1].ToString();
           registration = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][2].ToString();
           mileage = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][3].ToString();
           yearMade = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][4].ToString();
           price = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][5].ToString();
           imageNav = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index][6].ToString();  
        }

        public static void insertStaffRecord(string Name, string Password)
        {
            // This method will be used on Form4 to insert a new row into the staff table

            // create the row and add it to the dataset
            DataRow staffRow = ds2.Tables["tblStaff"].NewRow();
            staffRow[0] = Name;
            staffRow[1] = Password;

            ds2.Tables["tblStaff"].Rows.Add(staffRow);

            // update the database
            da.Update(ds2, "tblStaff");
        }

        public static void insertCarRecord(string Make,string Model,string Registration, string Mileage, string yearMade, string Price, string CarPhoto)
        {
            // This method will be used on Form4 to insert a new row into the cars table 

            // create the row and add it to the dataset
            DataRow carsRow = ds1.Tables["tblCars"].NewRow();
            carsRow[0] = Make;
            carsRow[1] = Model;
            carsRow[2] = Registration;
            carsRow[3] = Mileage;
            carsRow[4] = yearMade;
            carsRow[5] = Price;
            carsRow[6] = CarPhoto;

            ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows.Add(carsRow);

            // update the database
            da.Update(ds1, "tblCars");
        }

        public static void deleteRecord()
        {
            // This method will be used to delete a row of data from the cars table
            ds1.Tables["tblCars"].Rows[Index].Delete();

            //update the database
            da.Update(ds1, "tblCars");
        }

        public static void clearValues()
        {
            // This method will set all data to blank for loading the admin page

            make = "";
            model = "";
            registration = "";
            mileage = "";
            yearMade = "";
            price = "";
            imageNav = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exceptions:

for the insertStaffRecord() method:

> InvalidOperationException - Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.

for the inserCarRecord() method:

> InvalidOperationException - Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.

and finally for the deleteRecord() method:

> InvalidOperationException - Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions are saying that you need to provide the Insert and Delete SQL commands to the OleDbDataAdapter. Please see the MSDN page: [DataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)

Comment: @Phan Tomwolf Programming is not magic. If you used the code before and it works, and then you copied and pasted it and now it does not, either something circumstantial has changed that means the code is no longer doing the same job you thought it was, or you changed something about how it is used or edited it in some way that made it break.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide DataAdapter with queries to use for update and insert. I have no idea what was in the code you've copied it from, but here it's clear.
I think you can use [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets12p5.html) as an example of how to populate the adapter, it's for the beginner level.